# Getting Ormauth to work in FuelPHP

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

Ok, this is probably a easy, dumb question, but I can't find it online so:

How do I get `oil refine migrate --packages=auth` to properly select a database?

I've copied `auth.php` and `ormauth.php` to `app/config` and put my DB connection in all `db.php` files I could find!

I run Zend Server 6.1.0 on Ubuntu 13.04.
I use `/usr/local/zend/bin/php oil refine migrate --packages=auth` but it just keeps throwing these errors:

```
#0 /var/www/fuelphp/fuel/core/classes/database/pdo/connection.php(89): PDO->__construct('', NULL, NULL, Array)
#1 /var/www/fuelphp/fuel/core/classes/database/connection.php(708): Fuel\Core\Database_PDO_Connection->connect()
#2 /var/www/fuelphp/fuel/core/classes/dbutil.php(577): Fuel\Core\Database_Connection->connection()
#3 /var/www/fuelphp/fuel/core/classes/migrate.php(590): Fuel\Core\DBUtil::table_exists('migration')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had installed `php5-cli` which I shouldn't

Solution was adding `/usr/local/zend/bin` to the PATH variable after uninstalling `php5-cli`